# Creating node via REST POST gives "leaked cache metadata" error

Tags: nodes, 8

I'm trying to create new nodes by `POST`ing to `/entity/node?_format=json`.
This is the body I'm sending:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "type": {
            "href": "http:\/\/my.drupal.be\/rest\/type\/node\/group_of_documents"
        }
    },
    "title": [{
        "value": "Direct test - type 682"
    }],
    "body": [{
        "value": ""
    }],
    "field_owner": [{
        "value": "Symfony"
    }],
    "field_type": [{
        "target_id": "682"
    }]
}
```

And, in a way, this works. Because the document gets made, and everything is filled in.

But I keep getting an error:

```
A fatal error occurred:
The controller result claims to be providing relevant cache metadata,
but leaked metadata was detected.
Please ensure you are not rendering content too early.
Returned object class: Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse.
```

If I create a node without `field_type`, it doesn't throw an error.

`field_type` is the only field that has the **Reference type -> Reference views -> Reference method** set to `Views: Filter by an entity reference view`. Does that have anything to do with it?

Comment: same happened to me on REST GET when called Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => $node->id()], $options);
      $url->toString();

Comment: Getting the same thing when using snippet similar to @Adi

Answer (score 3):

That's a core bug, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2626298 and https://www.drupal.org/node/2663638 (either of those two would avoid this).

The views reference thing is a good hint. Sounds something runs there that then triggers this exception. You could open an issue for that too if you can find the exact reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing response to (maybe helps you) after you save node, because ResourceResponse is cachable...in this way we don't cache POST method.

```
return new ModifiedResourceResponse($node);
```

https://tutel.me/c/drupal/questions/249627/logicexception+node+save+via+resourcebase+post#